# Using <cfinvoke> in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusionbuilder

I would like to write a server-side validation code to validate all user inputs on my page. I would like to keep all these server-side validations from the presentation layer. Now I am looking into creating a component and keep all validation functions inside it. I will use **`<cfinvoke>`** tag to access validation methods on my user page. But the problem is I have to apply validation on around 50 user inputs and need to use `<cfinvoke>` tag 50 times. Can anyone tell me that using **`<cfinvoke>`** many times will affect performance or is there any other better approach that I can go with?

Answer (score 3):

There's no noticable overhead using `<cfinvoke>`. But I would still recommend you to avoid it here. Instead consider this (example):

Validator.cfc

```
<cfcomponent>

    <cffunction name="validateX" access="public" ...>
        ...
    </cffunction>
    <cffunction name="validateY" access="public" ...>
        ...
    </cffunction>
    <cffunction name="validateZ" access="public" ...>
        ...
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

controller.cfm

```
<cfset validator = new Validator()>

<cfset validator.validateX(...)>
<cfset validator.validateY(...)>
<cfset validator.validateZ(...)>
...
```

Now you can easily work with the validation result.

If you return boolean:

```
<cfif validator.validateX(...)>
    ...
<cfelse>
    ...
</cfif>
```

If you return an array with errors:

```
<cfset errors = []>
<cfset errors.addAll( validator.validateX(...) )>
<cfset errors.addAll( validator.validateY(...) )>
<cfset errors.addAll( validator.validateZ(...) )>
```

etc.

`<cfinvoke>` creates an instance of the Class (`new Validator()`) and invokes the method `validateX(...)` the same way. The major difference is: the instance is created on every `<cfinvoke>` anew and the return has to be specified as input variable (`returnVariable`), which is cumbersome in most cases.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Can you explain the difference of using <cfinvoke> and your way? I am new to Cold fusion. Your way seems to more readable.

Comment: Yes, the `new` operator was freshly introduced in CF9. I added an explaination to my answer at the bottom regarding the different approaches.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your help.

Comment: One other note: `New` will call the `init()` function of your method. Of course, you could also use `createObject()` or `cfobject`, too, but `New` is most often my choice.